# How to implement single selection in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I can change properties of selected item in RecyclerView but I want to remove selection for older selections.

Here is how I create RecyclerView :

```
fragmentViewPagerAdapter.addFragmentView((arg1, arg2, arg3) -> {
        View view = arg1.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout, arg2, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        selectDateRecyclerViewAdapter = new SelectDateRecyclerViewAdapter(dayList,this,(v,position) ->
        {
            AppCompatButton appCompatButton = (AppCompatButton)v.findViewById(R.id.selectHourButton);
            AppCompatImageView appCompatImageView = (AppCompatImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.calendarDot);
            highlightButton(appCompatButton,appCompatImageView);
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(selectDateRecyclerViewAdapter. new CalendarItemDecoration(10,dayList.size()));
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),4,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(selectDateRecyclerViewAdapter);
        selectDateRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    });
```

highlightButton method changes background of Button etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to hold flags to record which buttons are selected, when you select a new item, clear the flags first and reset it to the position of your new selected item. Then `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()`.done.

The main code of this function may be placed in `highlightButton` method. so It's better If you post the `highlightButton` code.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a single selection, you can track the selected position using an external variable, say int selectedIndex;

In your adapter code :

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                View itemView;        
                public ViewHolder(View v) {
                    super(v);
                    itemView = v;
                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            selectedPostion = getAdapterPosition();
                            if( selectedPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;
                            recyclerViewOnItemClickListener.onItemSelect(itemView, getAdapterPosition()); //Custom listener - in turn calls your highlightButton method

                            //call notifyDataSetChanged(); or notifyItemRangeChanged();
                            }
                    });
                }
            }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            holder.itemView.setSelected(position == selectedPostion);
     }
```